# Pyspark: How to use salting technique for Skewed Aggregates

Tags: pyspark, salt

How to use salting technique for Skewed Aggregation in Pyspark.

Say we have Skewed data like below how to create salting column and use it in aggregation.

| city | state | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lachung | Sikkim | 3,000 |
| Rangpo | Sikkim | 50,000 |
| Gangtok | Sikkim | 3,00,000 |
| Bangalore | Karnataka | 2,50,00,000 |
| Mumbai | Maharashtra | 2,90,00,000 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the salting technique on skewed data, we need to create a column say "salt". Generate a random no with a range from 0 to (spark.sql.shuffle.partitions - 1).

Table should look like below, where "salt" column will have value from 0 to 199 (as in this case partitions size is 200). Now you can use groupBy on "city", "state", "salt".

| city | state | salt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lachung | Sikkim | 151 |
| Lachung | Sikkim | 102 |
| Lachung | Sikkim | 16 |
| Rangpo | Sikkim | 5 |
| Rangpo | Sikkim | 19 |
| Rangpo | Sikkim | 16 |
| Rangpo | Sikkim | 102 |
| Gangtok | Sikkim | 55 |
| Gangtok | Sikkim | 119 |
| Gangtok | Sikkim | 16 |
| Gangtok | Sikkim | 10 |
| Bangalore | Karnataka | 19 |
| Mumbai | Maharashtra | 0 |
| Bangalore | Karnataka | 199 |
| Mumbai | Maharashtra | 190 |

code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StructType, StructField, IntegerType
)

salval = f.round(f.rand() * int(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")) -1 )

record_df.withColumn("salt", f.lit(salval).cast(IntegerType()))\
    .groupBy("city", "state", "salt")\
    .agg(
      f.count("city")
    )\
    .drop("salt")
```

output:

| city | state | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lachung | Sikkim | 3,000 |
| Rangpo | Sikkim | 50,000 |
| Gangtok | Sikkim | 3,00,000 |
| Bangalore | Karnataka | 2,50,00,000 |
| Mumbai | Maharashtra | 2,90,00,000 |